# Changing the current time zone on Ubuntu with C#/Mono

Tags: c#, datetime, mono

I'm modifying the time zone by replacing the file `/etc/locatime` by one in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` in a C#/Mono application, it nearly works.

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("a) Current Time zone: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName);
Console.WriteLine("a) Now: {0}", DateTime.Now);

// Changing /etc/locatime from CET to PST ...

TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();

Console.WriteLine("b) Current Time zone: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName);
Console.WriteLine("b) Now: {0}", DateTime.Now);
```

And here is the ouput:

```
a) Current Time zone: CET
a) Now: 10/20/2012 2:00:26 PM
b) Current Time zone: PST
b) Now: 10/20/2012 2:00:26 PM
```

As you can see the time zone is correct but `DateTime.Now`, which should return the local time, doesn't work and returns twice the same value.

Here is the version of mono I'm using:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Does someone have an idea about this issue?

Comment: Most standard C libraries read the local time zone information (preferentially from the environment variable `TZ` or otherwise by reading a system-dependent default) only once, the first time it is needed. If you want an application to pick up new timezone information, you can try calling the C library function `tzset()` to reset the timezone cache. I don't know how you can call `tzset()` from C#/Mono.

Answer (score 1):

As Celada pointed out - most C libraries only read it once.  `DateTime.Now` calls `gettimeofday()` on Linux.

This is the same on Windows, you don't even need any .NET application, simply open Windows Power Shell , type `date`, then change the timezone in Control Panel and type `date` again in that same Power Shell window.  It doesn't pick up the time zone change.  Only newly started processes get the new time zone.

Comment: `gettimeofday` returns an UTC time. It's event worse than I though, even without changing the time zone `DateTime.Now` is wrong. 

For example (the time zone is "Europe/Zurich") if I set the date to "2012.10.30 12:00 UTC" `DateTime.Now` returns "2012.10.30 13:00" which is correct, then is set the date to "2012.10.20 12:00 UTC" `DateTime.Now` returns "2012.10.30 13:00" which is wrong, it must be "2012.10.30 14:00".

Comment: At least `DateTime.UtcNow` is always correct and equals to the value returned by `gettimeofday` ...